# Postgresql pg_dump adding public to all schema names

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm still a relative newbie to Postgresql, so pardon if this is simple ignorance.

I've setup a active/read-only pacemaker cluster of Postgres v9.4 per the cluster labs documentation.

I'm trying to verify that both databases are indeed in sync.  I'm doing the dump on both hosts and checking the diff between the output.  The command I'm using is:

```
pg_sql -U myuser mydb >dump-node-1.sql
```

Pacemaker shows the database status as 'sync' and querying Postgres directly also seems to indicate the sync is good... (Host .59 is my read-only standby node)

```
psql -c "select client_addr,sync_state from pg_stat_replication;"
+---------------+------------+
|  client_addr  | sync_state |
+---------------+------------+
| 192.16.111.59 | sync       |
+---------------+------------+
(1 row)
```

However, when I do a dump on the read-only host I end up with all my tables having 'public.' added to the front of the names.  So table foo on the master node dumps as 'foo' whereas on the read-only node it dumps as 'public.foo'.  I don't understand why this is happening...  I had done a 9.2 Postgresql cluster in a similar setup and didn't see this issue.  I don't have tables in the public schema on the master node...

Hope someone can help me understand what is going on.

Much appreciated!

Comment: What are the **exact** versions of Postgres installed on the master and the slave? (`select version();`)

Comment: There is a difference.  Slave is running 9.4.15 (Debian 4.9.2-10) and the slave is running 9.4.18 on x86_46 (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1).  Our environment is debian Jessie.  Thank you "a_horse_with_no_name"... I wouldn't have caught that without the select version difference!

Comment: There were some security changes in the latest patch releases that influenced the way a dump is written. So 9.4.18 behaves differently regarding that compared to 9.4.15. Check the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-4-18.html)

Comment: I had run the apt-get dist-upgrade, but apparently neither I nor the dpkg restarted the Postgres daemon.  I thought they were both already updated to 9.4.18, but your "select version();" identified the issue.  I restarted Postgres and now the dumps are identical.  I'll move this to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), the security updates in 9.4.18 changed the way the dump is written compared to 9.4.15.  I didn't catch that one node was still running an older version.  The command that identified the problem was his suggestion to run:

```
psql -c "select version();"
```